# Openwrt lan configuration dhcp bogus ip addresses given

Tags: router, dhcp, openwrt

When I configure my network to use an IP address other then `192.168.1.1` connecting devices are given a bogus IP address such as `169.254.5.54`. Am I missing a configuration setting somewhere that would enable me to set my lan interface to `192.168.10.1` and get DHCP addresses of `192.168.10.*`? Chaos Calmer 15.05 is being used.

Here are my settings:
`/etc/config/network`

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd70:bf5f:ddc6::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option gateway '109.193.64.50'
    option dns '127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname '@wan'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 2 3 4 5'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '1 6'
```

`/etc/config/dhcp`

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option strictorder '1'
    list server '8.8.8.8'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'
    option ra_management '1'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'

config domain
```

Comment: "given a bogus IP address such as 169.254.5.54" that's not a bogus address - Used for link-local addresses between two hosts on a single link when no IP address is otherwise specified, such as would have normally been retrieved from a DHCP server.

Comment: Under config DHCP lan, you don't seem to have a ipv4 option set.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart `start` is set to 100. Since this is the network address offset as specified [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp) when my lan IP is `192.168.10.1` I should get DHCP addresses starting around `192.168.10.100`. Based on the example configurations I do not see a setting for ipv4 that I am missing.

Comment: @DavidPostill with a router address of `192.168.10.1` and a DHCP client address of `169.254.5.54`, I can not do much on the network. Do you mean that in this case DHCP is not giving out addresses at all?

Comment: @theurere Yes, exactly that. It gets a 169.254..x.x address when it fails to get an address from a DHCP server. Possibilities include no DHCP server specified, DCHP server specified but not reachable, faulty network cable, faulty LAN card driver, faulty LAN card, ... and probably many more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DavidPostill pointed me in the right direction. I changed the following to get dhcp working with an eth0 lan interface IP address of `192.168.10.1`. You can't do all of these changed in the LuCI website configuration so you have to ssh into the router and make the changes.

`/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'lan'
    option ipaddr '192.168.10.1'
```

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.10.1
```

In `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` comment out line 409:

```
# append_bool "$cfg" ignore "--no-dhcp-interface=$ifname" && return 0
```

Remove saved dhcp addresses in `/tmp/dhcp.leases`. Do a reboot.

If this didn't work simply manually assign your computer a static IP address, log back into the router, and look at the generated dhcp configuration under `/var/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. Make changes and restart dnsmasq with `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`.